# Compare with result in jquery in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to compare the result in codeigniter view page. I added the code for getting the dynamic records. I used the checkbox to get the value for compare details. The problem was while I uncheck the data which does not remove and next data not coming in front while close the value. Please tell me some suggestions to compare the details.

Please find the below code for more information.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="table mt10 revelx">
<thead>
<tr>
<th nowrap="" align="left">Sailing Date</th>
<th width="18%" align="center"> <b>Inside</b> </th>
<th width="18%" align="center"> <b>Oceanview</b> </th>
<th width="18%" align="center"> <b>Balcony</b> </th>
<th width="18%" align="center"> <b>Suite</b> </th>
<th align="center">Compare</th>
<th class="noborder">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="per_month1234">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   25th March 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>714.55USD</span> </td>
<td>
<div>796.36USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>905.45USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>969.09USD</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352905" value="352905" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352905" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_day1234" style="display: none;">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   25th March 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>238.18USD<br>Per Day</span> </td>
<td>
<div>265.45USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>301.82USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>323.03USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352905" value="352905" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352905" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_month1234">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   1st April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>605.45USD</span> </td>
<td>
<div>678.18USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>769.09USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>832.73USD</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352887" value="352887" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352887" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_day1234" style="display: none;">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   1st April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>201.82USD<br>Per Day</span> </td>
<td>
<div>226.06USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>256.36USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>277.58USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352887" value="352887" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352887" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_month1234">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   8th April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>605.45USD</span> </td>
<td>
<div>678.18USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>769.09USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>832.73USD</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352894" value="352894" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352894" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_day1234" style="display: none;">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   8th April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>201.82USD<br>Per Day</span> </td>
<td>
<div>226.06USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>256.36USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>277.58USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352894" value="352894" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352894" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_month1234">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   15th April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>605.45USD</span> </td>
<td>
<div>678.18USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>769.09USD</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>832.73USD</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352878" value="352878" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352878" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
<tr class="per_day1234" style="display: none;">
<td id="date_sort"> <a class="loder123" href="#">   15th April 2016</a> </td>
<td> <span>201.82USD<br>Per Day</span> </td>
<td>
<div>226.06USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>256.36USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td>
<div>277.58USD<br>Per Day</div>
</td>
<td align="center"> <input type="checkbox" class="compare_checkbox" id="352878" value="352878" name=""> </td>
<td align="center"> <a href="#"><input type="submit" class="button loder123" id="select_data352878" value="Select"></a> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="max_id" id="max_id" style="display: none;"> </tbody>
<tbody> </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="" class="relative_div red box">
<div class="bg_gray">
<div id="dmhd" class="">

<div id="data2" class="col-md-2"> </div>
<div id="data3" class="col-md-2"> </div>
<form method="POST" action="#">
<input type="hidden" id="value1" name="value1" value="352905"> <input type="hidden" id="value2" name="value2" value=""> <input type="hidden" id="value3" name="value3" value=""> 
<div class="col-md-2">
<input type="submit" class="button mt10 loder123" name="submit" value="Compare"> 
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and I added the script like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
}else{
}
var status = this.checked;
var n = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
if(n >= 1){
$(".red").show();
}else{
$(".red").hide();
}
if(n ==1 ){
var status_id = $(this).attr("id");

if(status_id !=""){
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id,'n':1}
}).done(function(data) {
$('#value1').val(status_id);
$('#data1').html(data);
});
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare_data",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id }
}).done(function(data) {
$('.data1a').html(data);
});
$("#data1").mouseover(function(){
$('.data1a').show();
$('.data2a').hide();
$('.data3a').hide();
});
}
}else if(n ==2 ){
var status_id = $(this).attr("id");

if(status_id !=""){
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id,'n':2}
}).done(function(data) {


$('#value2').val(status_id);
$('#data2').html(data);
});
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare_data",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id}
}).done(function(data) {



$('.data2a').html(data);
});
$("#data2").mouseover(function(){
$('.data1a').hide();
$('.data2a').show();
$('.data3a').hide();
});
}
}else if(n ==3 ){
var status_id = $(this).attr("id");

if(status_id !=""){
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id,'n':3}
}).done(function(data) {

$('#value3').val(status_id);
$('#data3').html(data);
});
$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo base_url();?>search_categories/get_compare_data",
type:'POST',
data:{'status_id':status_id}
}).done(function(data) {

$('.data3a').html(data);

});
$("#data3").mouseover(function(){
$('.data1a').hide();
$('.data2a').hide();
$('.data3a').show();

});
}
}


});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var day = document.getElementById('checkboxId');
if(day.checked == true){   // when checked
  write your code here..
}
if(day.checked == false){
  // reset all the value
   write your code after unchecked
}
```